# Error while using while read; do grep

Tags: bash, while-loop, grep, cat

I am using this command

```
cat text.csv | while read a ; do grep $a text1.csv >> text2.csv; done
```

text.csv has file names with full path. The file names are having spaces.

Example: C:\Users\Downloads\File Name.txt

text1.csv contains logs showing user id and the file name with full path.

Example: MyName,C:\Users\Downloads\File Name.txt

When I run the command, I get and error

```
grep: Name: No such file or Directory
```

I know that the error is because of the spaces in the file name. I would like to know how can I remove this error.

Comment: Unless order is important, you're better off with `grep -F -f text.csv text1.csv` (omit the `-F` if you really want regex metacharacters, not verbatim matching).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use your grep pattern with double quotes otherwise shell will treat it as different arguments to grep:

```
while read a ; do grep "$a" text1.csv >> text2.csv; done < text.csv
```

There is NO need of extra `cat` hence I changed it in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Quote the variable:

```
cat text.csv | while read a ; do grep "$a" text1.csv >> text2.csv; done
```

In general, you should usually quote variables, unless you specifically want the value to undergo word splitting and wildcard expansion.